# Combine MySQL Queries?

Tags: mysql, message

I'm trying to structure a Query for something that can best be compared to a multi-user messaging system.

The way I have it set up currently is with two databases, "Messages", and "Message_Recipients" shown below:

```
Messages
+------------+---------+--------------+------------+
| Message_ID | Message | Message_Type |  Completed |
+------------+---------+---------------------------+
|     1      |  Test   |     Task     |      0     |
+------------+---------+---------------------------+
Message_Recipients
+-------+------------+--------------+
| MR_ID | Message_ID | Recipient_ID |
+-------+------------+--------------+
|   1   |      1     |       25     |
+-------+------------+--------------+
```

My query is currently set up as follows:

```
$Q_Get_Tasks = "SELECT m.Message_ID, m.Message
    FROM Messages m
    WHERE m.Message_Type = 'Task'
    AND m.Completed = 0
    ORDER BY m.Message_ID";
```

I want to make it so that it only returns results which the user is a recipient for.  My idea was to do what's shown below, but I keep getting errors when I try it.

```
$Q_Get_Tasks = "SELECT m.Message_ID, m.Message
    FROM Messages m
    **JOIN Message_Recipients mr ON (m.Message_ID = mr.Message_ID)**
    WHERE m.Message_Type = 'Task'
    AND m.Completed = 0
    **AND mr.Recipient_ID = '$UserID'**
    ORDER BY m.Message_ID";
```

Can anyone provide some advice on this?

Comment: What kind of errors do you keep getting? The query itself looks valid (I suppose '**' chars is a typo and $UserID is correctly substituted)

Comment: I concur with ffeast. There's nothing obviously wrong with the SQL, except for the `**` characters which would cause a syntax error, and apart from the apparent SQL Injection vulnerability.  We have no idea what the variable `$UserID` contains, so Little Bobby Tables could be causing syntax errors, or more disturbing, be causing nefarious behavior without throwing any errors. For debugging this, I suggest you echo/print/vardump the contents of the $Q_Get_Tasks string, and test it from a different client. I also recommend you use a *prepared statement* with a *bind placeholder*.